# using Azure::Data::Table and pagination, Values is not accessible (C++ CLR)

Tags: c++, clr, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I have a code

```
Azure::Pageable<TableEntity^>^ response = table->Query<TableEntity^>(filter, maxPerPage, selection, cancellationToken);

auto pages = response->AsPages(ContinuationToken, maxPerPage);
    
auto enumerator = pages->GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator->MoveNext())
{
    auto current = enumerator->Current;
    int count = current->Values->Count;   <-- error here
}
```

In fact looking at the defintion Values exist and is a property with get

[image]

Same if i access the ContinuationToken propert

The error is

```
error C2039: 'get': is not a member of 'Azure::Page<Azure::Data::Tables::TableEntity ^>::Values'
```

Which doesnt make sense since when I try to run the application without the line that has the error and "watch" the current variable, the property Values is there and it is Enumerable as well as the ContinuationToken which is a string.

[image]

There is no other way to access the Values.
What am I missing here?